# How to access the DOM element of the child component in Preact with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, preact

I am using Preact with hooks. I have following button component:

```
export function Button(props) {
    return (
        <button class={props.class}>{props.children}</button>
    );
}
```

I have another parent component where I need to access actual DOM element button for animation purpose.

```
export function Parent(props) {
    const buttonElm = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log(buttonElm.current);

        // Animate button using popmotion or similar
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Button ref={buttonElm}>Click me to animate</Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, there is a problem. The `buttonElm.current` points to JSX object i.e. `Button` but not the DOM element `button`. I need `buttonElm` to point to actual DOM element. **How do I do that?**

> *Should I go ahead and use `buttonElm.current.base` property? But that does not feel idiomatic with hooks.*

Also, I have two questions.

1. How does `ref` behave when I am setting it on a Preact component that returns multiple elements using `<Fragment />`.
2. Second, is accessing the children's DOM element for animation purpose acceptable/correct practice in Preact/React? *(I can wrap my component in another wrapper `div` but that causes more animation headaches than solving the problem)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `ref` as `props` to your child component. By doing this `buttonElm` will point to  actual Button DOM element.

```
  export function Button(props) {
        return (
            <button class={props.class} ref={props.buttonElm}>{props.children}</button>
        );
    }

export function Parent(props) {
    const buttonElm = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log(buttonElm.current);

        // Animate button using popmotion or similar
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Button buttonElm={buttonElm}>Click me to animate</Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes that can work! Is this the practice generally followed? Or am I breaking the encapsulation too much?

Comment: No, `ref` is used to access DOM nodes and passing it as props is not bad practise. What you are doing is right, you just make mistake while referring `ref` to actual dom